# Getting quaternion to rotate between two vectors

Tags: math, geometry

I've got a pair of vectors. How can I create a quaternion that rotates from one to the other?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding quaternion representing the rotation from one vector to another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171849/finding-quaternion-representing-the-rotation-from-one-vector-to-another)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A unit quaternion **q** = cos(F)+**u***sin(F) represents the rotation of vector **v** by the angle 2*F about axis **u**.

If your vectors are **v** and **w**, then we should normalize them, then calculate the angle between them as 2*F=ArcCos(Dot(**v**, **w**)). Rotation axis direction vector **u** = Normalize(VectorProduct(**v**, **w**)). Now we can build required rotation quaternion.

Comment: It might also be a good idea to normalize the rotation axis **u** after it's been computed to sustain a unit quaternion, as the cross product of two unit vectors is only normalized for orthogonal input vectors.

Comment: @Christian Rau  You are right, I've missed this normalization. Added.

Comment: Note that the case v = −w needs special handling.