# Quaternions - how to limit axis?

Tags: 3d, quaternions

Is there any possibility to limit quaternions to move only in x & y axis (like in Eulers- yaw and pitch, without rolling)? I's there any equation or something similar to do this?

Some example:

Movement should behave like this: http://360.art.pl/experimental/1/
But when I build my player on quaternions it has no limits and I don't know how to fix it http://360.art.pl/experimental/2/

Comment: I'd love to help but quaternions totally do my head in. You might find some useful stuff regarding this over on Gamedev.se:  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=quaternion

Comment: The link is dead buddy. Could you post another one?

Answer (score 0):

Let me first describe the kind of constraint you're talking about.  Given an `world_up` vector, you want to limit your rotation such that it appears vertical with respect to the camera.  If the camera view coordinates are labeled `camera_up`, `camera_right`, and `camera_forward`:

```
constrain rotation matrix R such that:  dot(R*world_up, camera_right) == 0
```

This can be done straightforwardly (e.g., in [`LookAt()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml)-like functions) by constructing a set of perpendicular coordinate vectors as a function of the view direction, `view_forward`:

```
given vectors:  view_forward, world_up

Rot_forward = normalize(view_forward)
Rot_right = normalize( cross(view_forward, world_up) )
Rot_up = cross(Rot_right, Rot_forward)
```

---

To answer the question:  I could be wrong, but I don't think this kind of constraint is straightforward to implement in terms of quaternions.  It would be easier to generate the rotation matrix as above, and [convert it to a quaternion](http://www.euclideanspace.com/maths/geometry/rotations/conversions/matrixToQuaternion/).

That does raise a question: what problem are you trying to solve by using quaternions here?

- if you need quaternions to interface with some other system or library, that's fine.
- if you're trying to fix bad behavior, where the scene rotates quickly when your viewpoint is near the zenith, note that this is a consequence of your constraint:  it will happen regardless of how you implement it.
- if you're trying to use quaternions to get a more natural interpolation, note that your constraint renders this moot:  a natural quaternion interpolation will violate the constraint.  Given the constraint, it would be more natural to interpolate your `view_forward` vector, instead of your quaternion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to construct quaternions directly from yaw/pitch:

```
q = quat_from_axis_angle(up_vector, yaw) * quat_from_axis_angle(local_right, pitch)
```

(you may have to multiply these in the reverse order depending on how exactly you turn them into rotation matrices), or realign them every time you change them:

```
rotated_right = apply_rotation(q, local_right);
projected_right = rotated_right - dot(rotated_right, up_vector) * up_vector;
realign = quat_align_vector(rotated_right, normalized(projected_right));
q = realign * q
```

`projected_right` here is a projection of `rotated_right` onto the horizontal plane. Without rolling, these two vectors must be the same, which implies `dot(rotated_right, up_vector) = 0`. The last equation is the actual constraint that must be satisfied. It is quadratic in `q`. E.g. for `local_right=(1,0,0)`, and `up_vector=(0,0,1)`, it becomes `dot(q*(1i+0j+0k)*conj(q), 0i+0j+1k)=2*x*z-2*w*y=0`, with `q=w+xi+yi+zk`.

You can find formulas for `quat_from_axis_angle` and `apply_rotation` at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation. As for `quat_align_vector`, one way would be

```
quat_align_vector(src, dst) = sqrt([dot(src, dst), cross(src, dst)])
```

with `[a, b]` beign a quaternion with a real part `a`, and an imaginary part `b`. `Sqrt(x)` can be calculated as `exp(ln(x)/2)` (these functions are on the wiki, too). You could also try replacing sqrt with `exp(ln(x)/2*tick*realign_rate)` for a smooth restoration of the up-vector :) . Or go the opposite way and simplify the formula a bit:

```
quat_align_vector(src, dst) = [dot(halfway, dst), cross(halfway, dst)],
halfway = normalized(normalized(src) + normalized(dst))
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1171995.

EDIT: corrected vectors, added the constraint.